# Can Mayavi render a figure scene with a transparent background?

Tags: python, background, transparent, mayavi

I am generating a mesh plot using mayavi.mlab and want the background opacity to be 0. (or transparent). Is this possible?

Comment: What result are you expecting? More precisely, what do you expect to *do* with this transparent background? Are you trying to create images with some 3D rendered objects on some other background? Or perhaps are you trying to have your window manager composit the scene onto some other background? The first scenario is probably possible with postprocessing help. The second definitely isn't. Give more detail about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is to integrate the mayavi figure into a matplotlib figure, this is possible. You can use `mlab.screenshot` to get a numpy array of RGBA values, and `mlab` will set background pixels to have alpha `0` automatically. You can then add this RGBA matrix to a matplotlib figure via `imshow`. Example (adapted from [here](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.mesh)):

```
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# set up some plotting params
dphi, dtheta = np.pi / 250.0, np.pi / 250.0
[phi, theta] = np.mgrid[0:np.pi + dphi * 1.5:dphi,
                        0:2 * np.pi + dtheta * 1.5:dtheta]
m0, m1, m2, m3 = 4, 3, 2, 3
m4, m5, m6, m7 = 6, 2, 6, 4
r = np.sin(m0 * phi) ** m1 + np.cos(m2 * phi) ** m3 + \
    np.sin(m4 * theta) ** m5 + np.cos(m6 * theta) ** m7
x = r * np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
y = r * np.cos(phi)
z = r * np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
# do the meshplot    
fig = mlab.figure(size=(480, 340))
mlab.mesh(x, y, z, colormap='cool', figure=fig)
imgmap = mlab.screenshot(figure=fig, mode='rgba', antialiased=True)
mlab.close(fig)
# do the matplotlib plot
fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 5))
plt.imshow(imgmap, zorder=4)
plt.plot(np.arange(0, 480), np.arange(480, 0, -1), 'r-')
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

[image: mayavi meshplot composited onto matplotlib line graph]

You can also just save the RGBA array directly to file using `plt.imsave(arr=imgmap, fname="foo.png")`

Comment: When I run that exact code, it does not work (i.e. the mayavi figure has a gray background instead of transparent).

Comment: It works just fine for me: `mayavi` version `4.5.0` & `matplotlib` version `1.5.1`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the transparency directly. However, you can save the figure with a background colour (different than the foreground colour) and use ImageMagick to remove the background

For example

```
mlab.figure(size = (1024,768),\
            bgcolor = (1,1,1), fgcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

# Your fantastic plotting script

mlab.save('pure_beauty.png')
```

now use ImageMagick to remove the background

```
convert pure_beauty.png -transparent white pure_transparent_beauty.png
```

like shown [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16120/batch-replacing-color-with-transparency).