# How would you render a 3D arrow (cone + cylinder) onto a 2D image in Python without OpenGL?

Tags: python, plot, 3d, render

Assuming I've been given image `I` and a 3D vector `V_3d = [V_x, V_y, V_z]`. To make things easier, assume they're both in the same coordinate system. That is, the image plane normal is `Z` axis. The `Y` axis points downwards and `X` points to the right.

The closest example:
[image]

Their [solution](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AUvmhpHklM9BNt0Mn5DjSo3JRuqKkU4y) is complicated and requires OpenGL.

Comment: Mayavi with background image. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703417/can-mayavi-render-a-figure-scene-with-a-transparent-background

Comment: https://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#mayavi.mlab.quiver3d